# NASM macro calling a procedure inside

Tags: assembly, macros, nasm

```
  %macro initother 2-*
    %xdefine otherfunc %1
    %rotate 1
    %assign argc %0
    %rep argc
      push %1
      %rotate 1
    %endrep
    call otherfunc
    %rep argc
      add esp,4
    %endrep
  %endmacro
```

I've sat down to analyze the code but I could not find why this macro is not workibg, it should call anotherFunction within the macro. It does not make me any errors, but it does not work properly as I described.

I would like help, to know if this macro works peoperly or not (maybe the problem is at otherfunc, but I just need to know if this macro works fine). Thank you!

Comment: You *haven't* described *how* it doesn't work; this isn't a [mcve].  What actually happens?  When you disassemble the binary, what do you see?  That will tell you if your macro expanded the way you wanted it to.  (And BTW, `add esp, 4*argc` would be more efficient than `%rep` to do multiple add instructions.)

Comment: The assignment seems like it should be `%assign argc %0 - 1` instead.

Comment: And the macro parameter count might be `1-*` instead.